# Ask ActiveDirectory if a machine is a member of a group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

This should be really easy but for some reason it doesn't seem to be.  I want to ask AD if the current machine is a member of a particular group.  Direct membership is fine.

Group only contains 8 PC's and is extremely unlikely to grow beyond 30.

C# code examples appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example method using the [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace:

```
public bool BelongsToGroup(string computerName, string groupName, string domain)
{
   PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);

   ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, computerName);

   foreach (Principal result in computer.GetGroups())
   {
      if (result.Name == groupName)
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

  return false;
}
```

So you could call it like this:

```
string computerName = Environment.MachineName;
string groupName = "Group Name";
string domainName = "Domain Name";
bool test = BelongsToGroup(computerName, groupName, domainName);
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much!  I have just spent 2 hours crying at LDAP error messages!!

Comment: You can also use: bool success = computer.IsMemberOf(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName); instead of the foreach - which, by the way, gave an error for me.

Comment: foreach also gave me an error, "IsMemberOf" method works flawlessly, thank you!